# Python, Pandas: Разбить период даты построчно

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

Прошу помочь разбить период даты построчно, как на примере:
[image: Пример]

Файл: [data.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WVur4cO1qAbbPLeQ3CoUKR4eie3HSA82/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117591734694246991906&rtpof=true&sd=true).

Answer (score 3):

Можно так:

```
df["дата отпуска"] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(start=row["отпуск с даты"], end=row["отпуск по дату"], freq="D"), axis=1)
res = df.explode("дата отпуска").set_index("дата отпуска").drop(columns=["отпуск с даты", "отпуск по дату"]).reset_index()
res = res[["Пользователь", "ID", "дата отпуска"]]
```

Теперь res:

```
   Пользователь   ID дата отпуска
0          Петя  111   2022-04-06
1          Петя  111   2022-04-07
2          Петя  111   2022-04-08
3          Петя  111   2022-04-09
4          Петя  111   2022-04-10
5          Петя  111   2022-04-11
6          Петя  111   2022-04-12
7          Вася  222   2022-06-01
8          Вася  222   2022-06-02
9          Вася  222   2022-06-03
10         Вася  222   2022-06-04
11         Вася  222   2022-06-05
```

Comment: Спасибо большое